# facebook session expires in android

Tags: java, android

i am using facebook api in my android project

```
{"error":{"type":"OAuthException","message":"Error validating access token:
Session has expired at unix time 1307350800.
The current unix time is 1307352870."}}
```

My session expires....after a while....i want it as session never...expires

expecting piece a piece code..so that session never endsup

am using this for authorizing

```
    facebook.authorize(SignIn.this,
                    new DialogListener() {
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to request the offline permission when the user signs in to get a token that doesn't expire.

```
getFacebookApi().authorize(this, new String[]{"offline_access"}, CONSTANT_ID, myDialogListener);
```

hope this helps!

Comment: is it possible without `offline_access` ? one more question: if i update the access_token will it update the expire time or the session ? 
my problem is exactly like Rockin's problem. But i don't want to do it with `offline_access` . @schwiz

Comment: @Shoshi the facebook apis have changed so much in the last year, I haven't kept up with them so I'm not sure, sorry.